# How to query and update in firestore v9

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
async booleanFunction(email: string, bool: boolean){
    console.log('here')
    const db = getFirestore();
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("email", "==", email), limit(1));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    await updateDoc(querySnapshot, {
      disabled: !bool
    });
}
```

Here is my function which takes in email and a bool value(this needs to be updated), I don't have the _id that firestore provides so I need some alternate to query data and update it

This the the error that shows up

```
Argument of type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<{ disabled: boolean; }>'.
```

Type 'QuerySnapshot' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentReference<{ disabled: boolean; }>': converter, type, firestore, id, and 3 more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
await updateDoc(querySnapshot, {
  disabled: !bool
});
```

You're trying to call `updateDoc` on a `QuerySnapshot`, which isn't possible and never has been possible on v8 either.

You can only call `updateDoc` on a `DocumentReference`. So you will have to loop over the documents in the `QuerySnapshot` and call `updateDoc` on each of them:

```
await Promise.all(() => 
  querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
    updateDoc(doc.ref, { disabled: !bool })
  )
)
```